# Download reiszed image with it's the new widh and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

Basically, I'm trying to resize an image an download it with it new width an height, but it only download the original verion of it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(function () {
            jQuery(":file").change(function () {
                if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

                    orginalWidth = $("#image").width();
                    orginalheight = $("#image").height();
                    // alert(orginalheight);
                    var images = jQuery('.thumb-wrapper img'); //caches the query when dom is ready
                    // var CELL_WIDTH = 150;
                    var ASPECT = 1.5;

                    jQuery( "#slider" ).slider({
                        step: 5,
                        min: 70,
                        max: 200,
                        value: 100,
                        slide: function(event, ui) {
                            var size = (orginalWidth * ui.value /10) + "px";
                            // alert(size);
                            images.stop(true).animate({width: size, height: size / ASPECT}, 250);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        function imageIsLoaded(e) {
            jQuery("#download").removeAttr("style");
            jQuery("#file").css("display", "none");
            jQuery('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
            jQuery('#download').attr('href', e.target.result);
        };

});
```

HTML :

```
<div id="slider"></div>

<div class="file-list">
 <div class="file-cell">
    <div class="thumb-wrapper">
        <input id="file" type='file' style=""/>
        <img id="image" src="#" alt="your image" />
        <a id="download" href="#" download="filename.jpg" style="display:none;">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's a [**Jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxvPe/)

Any solution for this ? Much appreciated!

Comment: I've done this for uploading but not downloading.  I could be wrong, but the first thing I'd do to achieve this is resample the file on the server then ajax get the resampled one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing right now is making the browser resize the image in the viewport, without altering the original image.
What you'll need to do is make a script to resize the image server-side. You use jQuery to post the image to the server and get the resized image back.

Comment: That is correct, just thought i would throw in the name of the library for PHP (GD) and a link to its docs. I totally agree with your answer +1 http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: He didn't mention what programming language he could use so I left that open. If he does use PHP a nice alternative to GD could be ImageMagick.

Comment: That is true, and its a fairly good guess considering the majority of websites run on PHP. I have only read on ImageMagick and heard good things.

Comment: Is there a script that can resize the image based on the img attribute width ?

Comment: I think you'll need to make a server script yourself. I'm not sure if there are prepared scripts for this task as it is rather small. You could use jQuery to send an image to the server together with the wanted width, then using Imagick you could resize it. Small example (in PHP): `$image = new Imagick('example_in.png'); $image->thumbnailImage(300, 0); $image->writeImage('example_out.png');`. This would give the image a width of 300px.